# Amazon AWS EMR "no" configuration sample application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

I registered for aws account yesterday and today i followed couple of videos on youtube to run a sample wordcount on input file in S3. 
I tried to do that but i don't see any "configuration sample application" button. I have attached an image. It may be trivial, since i am new i may be missing something.
Process i followed:

1. Created a bucket in S3
2. aws-> security credentials, created an access
3. key aws->EC2, created key pair
4. AWS->IAM, created new role as EC2 + administrator
5. AWS->EMR, create cluster

Here i don't see any option for configure sample application button. Please check image for more detail[image]

Comment: click up top on the advanced options, and look in the "Steps" section. i think its there

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EMR used to have a 'Sample Application' button, like this:

[image: Old EMR screen]

However, **that button is no longer available in the Amazon EMR interface**.

The tutorial is most probably out-of-date. (Things change fast on AWS!)